# Ajax get data from anchor id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run an ajax call function but I am running into issues. I'd like to grab the id as the data item for this. My code is below but I haven't seen any signs of it working yet.

Thanks for your help

```
<a class='ajax-read' id='133' href='#' >read more</a> 


   <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('.ajax-read').click(function(){
                    var elem = $(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/inc/read-more.php",
                        data: "id="+ id,
                        dataType:"json",  
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(data.success){
                                   elem.hide();
                                   $('#read-more-content').html(data.message);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
         </script>
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have local variable `id`. Try: `data: "id=" + this.id,`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the anchor id inside the AJAX call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.ajax-read').click(function(){
            var elem = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/inc/read-more.php",
                data: "id="+ elem.attr('id'),
                dataType:"json",  
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.success){
                        elem.hide();
                        $('#read-more-content').html(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
data: "id="+ id,
```

to

```
data: "id="+ elem.attr('id'),
```